Ingestion Settings Tab is missing
We have installed signoz v0.54.0 on AWS EC2 server, but we noticed that ingestion settings tab is missing and not shown, as per this doc https://signoz.io/docs/ingestion/signoz-cloud/keys/
My user is with admin role. We installed signoz via the Install Script as this doc https://signoz.io/docs/install/docker/#install-signoz-using-the-install-script
Any idea ?

have you found a solution? I have the same problem with signoz community edition installed using docker
